# cant get the android soft keyboard to appear/hide using viewpager

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-viewpager

In my application I am using viewPager to give me nice swipey views. I want the keyboard to be hidden in 2 of the pages but always diaplayed on one page, where I have a text box.

I have tried various ways to get the keyboard to display but it just does not work. I think I must be calling the display keyboard code in the wrong place.

```
 @Override
public Object instantiateItem( View collection, int position )
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = null;
    if(position==0){
        layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.other, null);
        //new PC().create(layout, context);
        ((InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(collection.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }else if(position==1){
        layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
        new BlurayRemote().create(layout,context);
        ((InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(collection.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }else if(position==2){
        layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.text, null);
        new TextInput().create(layout,context);
        ((InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInputFromInputMethod(collection.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(layout);

    return layout;      
}
```

Any help would be great as it is driving me mad!

Comment: Also, your activity will b re-created when you rotate your screen, thus the context will be changed; so in way, your pageadaptor is holding on to a context that should no longer exist, and will result in a memory leak!

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but I was having the same problem and I got around it by setting the parent `View` to focusable. That way, whatever is causing the soft keyboard from popping up will not receive focus when you swipe between pages.

```
<!-- Dummy item to prevent your View from receiving focus -->
<LinearLayout
    ...
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

    <!-- The view(s) that are causing the keyboard to pop up each time you swipe -->
    <EditText ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found that using the wrong context screws up things usually. Try this.

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem( View collection, int position )
{
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = null;
    if(position==0){
        layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.other, null);
        //new PC().create(layout, context);
        ((InputMethodManager)collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(collection.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }else if(position==1){
        layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
        new BlurayRemote().create(layout, collection.getContext());
        ((InputMethodManager)collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(collection.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }else if(position==2){
        layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.text, null);
        new TextInput().create(layout,collection.getContext());
        ((InputMethodManager)collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInputFromInputMethod(collection.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(layout);

    return layout;      
}
```

Comment: This works the first time but after a bit does not work any more. Any idea why?